# Flutter - PopupMenuItem onTap is not calling callback function

Tags: flutter, dart

in my flutter project here the same `callback` is working with when I press `onPressed` in the `TextButton.icon` widget itself but `onTap` is not working. I do know this when I press inside of `PopupMenuItem` but not exactly on `TextButton` in this case it's not working, but it works when I press on `TextButton`.
I did `onPressed:null` but `onTap` still not working.
My question is how can I call this callback by pressing anywhere inside `PopupMenuItem`?

```
PopupMenuItem(
  child: GestureDetector(
    behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
    child: TextButton.icon(
      onPressed: editTaskCallback,
      icon: const Icon(Icons.edit),
      label: const Text('Edit'),
    ),
  ),
  onTap: editTaskCallback,
),
```

Comment: Can you include full widget that will reproduce the same issue, you are assigning same `editTaskCallback`

Comment: Hi @YeasinSheikh. Here is the link to the full widget:
[link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WhfjB7nIy7w3xBXmSlvacq5zy8TE95CO/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Does the below post answer your question?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh, yeah, thanks, it helped to close the popup. But edit button is not pressed when I press a corner of the popup. I want it to be pressed when I press anywhere in popup

Comment: Can you check update answer

Answer (score 1):

You can combine the methods, use `Navigator.of(context).pop()` to close the `PopupMenuItem`.

```dart
 editTaskCallback(BuildContext context, bool fromOnTap) {
    debugPrint("tapped");
    if (!fromOnTap) Navigator.of(context).pop(); // will close the menu item
  }

///...

PopupMenuItem(
    child: TextButton.icon(
      onPressed: () {
        editTaskCallback(context, false);
      },
      icon: const Icon(Icons.edit),
      label: const Text('Edit'),
    ),
    onTap: () {
      editTaskCallback(context, true);
    }),
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find this solution to enable more pressable place in 'PopupMenuItem'

```
PopupMenuItem(
  child: IntrinsicWidth(
    child: Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
      children: [
        TextButton.icon(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
            editTaskCallback();
          },
          icon: const Icon(Icons.edit),
          label: const Text('Edit'),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
  onTap: null,
),
```